# What should I change in this two code block so that I can open different web pages

Tags: html, button

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me
            </label>
        </div>

        **<script>function openWin() {
                window.open("https://localhost:7257/Home/Stocks");
            }</script>
        <form>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" onclick="openWin()">
                Login
            </button>
        </form>

        <script>function openWin() {
                window.open("https://localhost:7257/Home/Signup");
            }</script>

        <form>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign up" onclick="openWin()">
                Sign up
            </button>
        </form>**

    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

After executing this code block the page that is similar to photo can be displayed but my problem is how should I change these 2 buttons functions so that they can pop up different locations like it is written in the bold area.

If there is any related page similar to this issue, you can share as comment.

Comment: Did you want to open them in new windows or just in the same tab?

Comment: I want them to lead their pre-defined link in the code but after clicking these 2 button separately, only the first pre-defined link was shown

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've named both functions openWin(). When you click the button it's finding the the top function and never makes it to the second one since it thinks it found what it was looking for. JS runs from top to bottom in order so as soon as it finds the first function it will stop.

You need to change one of the function names when you declare it, such as openWin() and openWin2().

I would also recommend that you move all of your JS code to a single `<script>` tag in order to avoid errors in the future.